# Filling a ggplot histogram based on parameter values used in a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame which looks like:

```
    price median_price_mts_alquiler  mts2
    <dbl>                     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 274500                      9.75    65
 2 169000                     13.2     32
 3 189000                     11.9     79
 4 428000                     10.7    172
 5  57500                      8.12    50
 6  52000                      6       50
 7  98500                      9.26   100
 8  58000                      6.25    65
 9  91500                      6.94    85
10  91500                      6.94    75
```

I also have some input parameters:

```
num_samples <- 1000
input_parameters = list(
  vacancies = rbeta(num_samples, shape1 = 1, shape2 = 10),
  operatingExpenses = rnorm(num_samples, mean = operatingExpenses, sd = 0.1),
  growthRateIncome = rnorm(num_samples, mean = growthRateIncome, sd = 0.02),
  growthRateExpenses = rnorm(num_samples, mean = growthRateExpenses, sd = 0.01)
)
```

Function to perform calcualtion:

```
dcf_calculation = function(price, median_price_mts_alquiler, mts2, vacancy, operatingExpense, growthRateIncome, growthRateExpense){
  T = 5
  potentialGrossRevenue = median_price_mts_alquiler*12 * mts2
  generalVacancy = potentialGrossRevenue * - vacancy
  effectiveGrossRevenue = potentialGrossRevenue + generalVacancy
  operatingExpense = mts2 * operatingExpense
  netOperatingIncome = effectiveGrossRevenue - operatingExpense
  # for the remaining years
  # for the remaining years
  potentialGrossRevenue_T = potentialGrossRevenue*(1+growthRateIncome)^(1:(T))
  generalVacancy_T = potentialGrossRevenue_T * - vacancy
  effectiveGrossRevenue_T = potentialGrossRevenue_T + generalVacancy_T
  
  operatingExpense_T = operatingExpense * (1+growthRateExpenses)^(1:(T))
  netOperatingIncome_T = effectiveGrossRevenue_T - operatingExpense_T
  
  # Valuation at sale
  ################################################################################
  netOperatingIncome_T = effectiveGrossRevenue_T - operatingExpense_T
  salePrice = netOperatingIncome_T[T] / capRate
  ################################################################################
  
  # Return analysis
  ################################################################################
  cashFlowOperations = c(netOperatingIncome, netOperatingIncome_T)[1:T]
  cashFlowStreams = c(price*-1, cashFlowOperations[1:T-1], cashFlowOperations[T] + salePrice)
  internalRateOfRetrun = jrvFinance::irr(cashFlowStreams)
  return(list(
    salePrice = salePrice, cashFlowStreams = cashFlowStreams, cashFlowOperations = cashFlowOperations, internalRateOfRetrun = internalRateOfRetrun))
}
```

Using a forloop I can apply this function using all of the parameters defined in the `input_parameters` as follows:

```
results_list <- list()
result = list()
# Loop through each row in the dataframe
for (i in 1:nrow(data_df)) {
  price <- data_df$price[i]
  median_price_mts_alquiler <- data_df$median_price_mts_alquiler[i]
  mts2 <- data_df$mts2[i]
  
  # Loop through each combination of parameters
  for (j in 1:num_samples) {
    vacancy <- input_parameters$vacancies[j]
    operatingExpense <- input_parameters$operatingExpenses[j]
    growthRateIncome <- input_parameters$growthRateIncome[j]
    growthRateExpense <- input_parameters$growthRateExpenses[j]
    
    # Apply the function and store the results
    result[[glue("MonteCarloSim_{j}")]] <- dcf_calculation(price, median_price_mts_alquiler, mts2, vacancy, operatingExpense, growthRateIncome, growthRateExpense)
    results_list[[glue("property_{i}")]] = result
    #results_list[[paste("Row", i, "_Sample", j)]] <- result
  }
}
```

This gives me the following output:

[image]

Then I can use the following to plot the histograms:

```
x = results_list %>% 
  map(., ~map(., ~ pluck(., "salePrice")))

library(patchwork)

p1 = x$property_3 %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value)) +
  geom_histogram()

input_1 = input_parameters$vacancies %>% data.frame() %>% set_names("vacancy") %>% ggplot(aes(x = vacancy)) + geom_histogram()
input_2 = input_parameters$operatingExpenses %>% data.frame() %>% set_names("operatingExpenses") %>% ggplot(aes(x = operatingExpenses)) + geom_histogram()
input_3 = input_parameters$growthRateIncome %>% data.frame() %>% set_names("growthRateIncome") %>% ggplot(aes(x = growthRateIncome)) + geom_histogram()
input_4 = input_parameters$growthRateExpenses %>% data.frame() %>% set_names("growthRateExpenses") %>% ggplot(aes(x = growthRateExpenses)) + geom_histogram()

p1 + ((input_1 | input_2) / (input_3 | input_4))
```

[image]

Now, I want to color the histograms so I can see when the `vacancy` rate is "high" where do these values affect the output of the "salePrcie" in the left-most histgoram (on the right we have the assumptions and on the left the "salePrice" from the DCF fucntion).

I am trying to have a "quick" overview of how higher/lower values in the distributions affect the "salePrice" / valuation - so if the `growthRateIncome` is high (right-side of the histogram) and `growthRateExpenses` is low (left-side of the histogram) then I would expect that this would have a "high" "salePrice" and be located on the right-side of the main histogram. - I just want to color some of these values.

Data:

```
data_df = structure(list(price = c(274500, 169000, 189000, 428000, 57500, 
52000, 98500, 58000, 91500, 91500), median_price_mts_alquiler = c(9.75, 
13.2142857142857, 11.9308035714286, 10.7142857142857, 8.125, 
6, 9.26282051282051, 6.25, 6.94444444444444, 6.94444444444444
), mts2 = c(65, 32, 79, 172, 50, 50, 100, 65, 85, 75)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```